# Variadic template method specialization

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

This is the code I currently have:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    template<typename T, typename... Args>
    void Function(T t1, Args... args){
        // Definition
    }

private:
    template<typename T>
    void Function(T t1){
        // Definition
    }
};
```

---

```
#include "header.h"

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.Function(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

Works just fine. When I try to separate the definition to source.cpp, the gcc starts complaining. I know I have to specialize the templates in order to separate the definition, so I tried adding the code below to the header file:

```
template<>
void Foo::Function<int, int...>(int t1, int... args);

template<>
void Foo::Function<int>(int);
```

but without success. What am I missing

---

edit: gcc error messages:

> header.h:15:28: error: expansion pattern ‘int’ contains no argument
>   packs  void Foo::Function(int t1, int... args);
>
> header.h:15:48: error: expansion pattern ‘int’ contains no argument
>   packs  void Foo::Function(int t1, int... args);

Comment: what you want to achieve?

Comment: _"Doesn't work"_ isn't a useful problem description. Provide a [mcve] reproducing the problen (including verbatim error messages) as required here please.

Comment: `int...` is not allowed. `...` is used to expand template parameter packs and `int..` is not a template. `void f(int...x)` cannot be a function, because there's no concrete signature. What do you want to do with `Function`? Perhaps `std::initializer_list` could be used instead of the pack, or simply `std::vector<int>`

Comment: @Quimby the end result should look something like: `Function(std::string id, make_pair("key", "value"), make_pair("another_key", "another_value"), ...);`

Comment: @Quimby it works just fine without specializations.. all I want to do is to move method definitions to a separate source file.

Comment: @Quest Yes, of course it does. But explicit specialization is no longer a template, so it won't work with them. Well in that case, you can use a `vector<T>` and add one pair of parantheses: `Function(std::string id,{ make_pair("key", "value"), make_pair("another_key", "another_value"), ...});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `int...` as a parameter pack, and so this doesn't work. In addition, to separate the source from the definition, you have to fully specify the template, so `int...` wouldn't work even if that syntax were allowed.

#### Ways to get around this.

**1. Make `Function` accept an initializer list.**
We can write function so that it accepts an initializer list of `int`s:

```
#include <initializer_list>

class Foo {
   public:
    void Function(int t1, std::initializer_list<int> t2);
};

void Foo::Function(int t1, std::initializer_list<int> t2) {
    for(int i : t2) {
        // stuff
    }
}
```

Now, you can call `Function` pretty easily, and it's not even templated:

```
Foo f; 
f.Function(10, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
```

If there are other places you're using templates, you can expand a parameter pack directly into the initializer list:

```
template<class... Args>
void invoke_foo(Foo& f, int first, Args... rest) {
    f.Function(first, {rest...}); 
}
```

**2. Use SFINAE to disable all non-int overloads.** We can disable all overloads of `Foo::Function` that don't only accept `int`s

```
#include <type_traits>

class Foo {
   public:
    // Requires C++17 for std::conjunction
    // You could write your own std::conjunction too if you'd prefer
    template<class... Args>
    auto Function(int t1, Args... t2)
        -> std::enable_if_t<std::conjunction<std::is_same<Args, int>...>::value>
    {
        // stuff
    }
};
```

The downside to this is that non-integral values won't automatically be converted to `int`.

Comment: What's the real difference between std::vector<int> and std::initializer_list<int>?

Comment: std::vector can be implicitly constructed from an initializer list. If you use std::vector then it'll 1) construct an initializer list, then 2) allocate memory for a vector, then 3) copy the values into the vector. It's cleaner and faster just to use an initializer list.

Answer (score 0):

There is better way to do it.
First of all it looks like you want to force same type of all arguments (this is done by `std::initializer_list` in accepted answer). This can be foreced by providing extra explicit argument:

```cpp
class Foo
{
public:
    template<typename T, typename... Args>
    void Function(T t1, T t2, Args... args)
    {
        LOG;
        this->Function(t1);
        this->Function(t2, args...);
    }

private:
    template<typename T>
    void Function(T t1)
    {
        LOG << VAR(t1);
    }
};

template<>
void Foo::Function<int>(int x)
{
    LOG << " Spec" << VAR(x);
}
```

As you can see it is enough if you provide specialization of method for single argument.

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/iZejP4QwCM6yCEpe)